# Print the sum of the squares of some numbers

Tags: code-golf, arithmetic

This is a little codegolf challenge from codingame.com. I was wondering how much Python3 code is necessary (but of course answers are not limited to Python3).

**Input**
The first line contains one positive integer n. The second line contains n positive integers. Each consecutive integers on the second line are separated by one space. There is no newline at the end of the second line.

**Output**
One line containing the sum of the squares of the numbers on the second input line, and no white space except an optional newline at the end.

Each entry must be a complete program with input and output, not only a function. Shortest code wins.

For example, input:

```
5
1 2 5 7 8
```

and output:

```
143
```

Comment: Can we take only one input? The first one is unnecessary

Comment: You do know you're changing IO allowed by default?  http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods/

Comment: Input #1=`len(input2.split())`

Comment: Can I have a link to the original question?

Comment: Can we take input as a list of integers? (i.e `[1,2,5,7,8]`)

Comment: I'm confused why you've posted both here *and* in the Sandbox ... http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/8827/42963

Comment: @CatsAreFluffy - There is no link to the original question, because codingame.com gives the challenges randomly; up to 8 people compete in a randomly selected challenge with a time limit of 10 or 15 minutes, and there is no way to go back and view the question after the time expires.

Comment: @DonMuesli -  The code that is submitted there is evaluated automatically, so the first line of input just is there, even though it is unnecessary

Comment: @Martin Büttner - It is not a competition, it just a casual time-passer. You may stumble over it multiple times, so I do not think that cheating is a problem. There is no permanent ranking. As to copyright, I do not think that copyright can cover the idea itself, and even if it would, this would be a fair use exception.

Comment: @muddyfish and quartata - Sorry about the IO. I stated it the way it was required by the question on codingame, because the first line of input was in the way, and I was wondering how many bytes of code it would take to handle it. input(input()) from CatsAreFluffy's answer saved one byte in this respect, as opposed to my initial code.

Comment: @Stewie Griffin - Well, I would prefer if we would stick to the input restrictions of the original problem (input as a list of integers would not be ok in this case) because I am still curious to see if anyone can further improve on the code size of the Python3 and C answers as far as input goes.

Comment: We've discussed the situation among the moderators and figured that the copyright is indeed probably not worth worrying about. However, the downvotes on your challenge are likely due to the fact that you've copied the input format verbatim from the source, and [cumbersome I/O formats](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/8077/12012) are one of the things to avoid when writing challenges. If you relaxed the rules a little, this challenge would probably blend in more nicely and be more well-received. Sorry about the premature deletion, and welcome to Programming Puzzles & Code Golf!

Answer (score 2):

## Jelly, 5 bytes

```
ṣ⁶V²S
```

[Try it online.](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=4bmj4oG34bmq4bmj4oG2VsKyUw&input=&args=NQoxIDIgNSA3IDg)

Input format is rather annoying....

### Explanation

```
ṣ⁶V²S
ṣ⁶       split by space
  V      map eval over the resulting list -- the newline in the first element causes the first line to be treated as a separate link and ignored
   ²     map square over the list
    S    sum
```

Comment: You can save three bytes by eliminating the first three bytes.

Comment: @Dennis Oh, that's clever. Thanks.

Comment: In case it isn't clear, `V` executes the string just as if it were a complete program. For the first string, the second line is the main link, and the first one isn't referenced, so it is ignored.

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 5 bytes

Code:

```
²ð¡nO
```

Explanation:

```
²      # Take the second input, the first input is ignored
 ð¡    # Split on spaces
   n   # Square each element
    O  # Take the sum and implicitly output it
```

Uses **CP-1252** encoding.

[Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=wrLDsMKhbk8&input=NQoxIDIgNSA3IDg)

Answer (score 2):

### Python 3, 52

```
i=input;print(sum(int(d)**2for d in i(i()).split()))
```

Comment: It is giving an unnecessary output. But that sound fair since there is an unnecessary input!

Comment: Yup, going by the rules...

Answer (score 1):

## [MATL](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MATL), 6 bytes

```
xjU2^s
```

[**Try it online!**](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=eGpVMl5z&input=NQoxIDIgNSA3IDg)

```
x    % take first input and throw it away
j    % take second input as a string
U    % convert to array with those numbers
2^   % element-wise square
s    % sum of array
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3, 54 bytes

*-[] thanks to shooqie*

```
print(sum(int(i)**2for i in input(input()).split()))
```

Takes input as specified in the first version of the question.

So to answer your question: Not a lot.

Comment: _first version_ :-D

Comment: Stupid me, testing in a REPL...

Comment: You don't need the square brackets: `print(sum(int(i)**2for i in input(input()).split()))`

Comment: @CatsAreFluffy and shooqie - Thank you, I was doing it in 56 bytes and was wondering what parts of the code are unnecessary. As opposed to my code, input(input()) saves one byte, 2for another and the square brackets another two.

Answer (score 1):

### [Pyke](https://github.com/muddyfish/PYKE), 10 bytes

```
;\ cFE2^)s
```

Takes input as requested

[Try it here](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=%3B%5C+cFE2%5E%29s&input=5%0A1+2+5+7+8) (Yay setup a try-it page!)

Or 5 bytes if allowed a list of ints:

```
2Rm^s
```

Or noncompeting (add squared node), 3 bytes

```
mXs
```

Answer (score 1):

### [Minkolang 0.15](https://github.com/elendiastarman/Minkolang), 9 bytes

```
n[n2;+]N.
```

[Try it here!](http://play.starmaninnovations.com/minkolang/?code=n%5Bn2%3B%2B%5DN%2E&input=5%0A1%202%205%207%208)

#### Explanation

```
n            Take number from input
 [    ]      Pop top of stack and repeat that many times
  n          Take number from input
   2;        Square it
     +       Add to top of stack
       N.    Output as number and stop.
```

Answer (score 1):

### CJam, 10 bytes

```
l;l~]2f#1b
```

[Test it here.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=l%3Bl~%5D2f%231b&input=5%0A1%202%205%207%208)

#### Explanation

```
l;   e# Read first line and discard.
l~   e# Read second line and evaluate, dumping all integers on the stack.
]    e# Wrap them in an array.
2f#  e# Square each.
1b   e# Sum.
```

Comment: `1b` is a nice trick

Comment: @DonMuesli I could probably use `:+` here, but `1b` became a habit because it also works as expected for empty arrays.

Answer (score 1):

## Octave, 45 bytes

Octave is not exactly designed for accepting random input formats. For instance, input over multiple lines is impossible. Also, numbers can't be entered as a list unless you have brackets. For that reason, the input must be taken as a string.

```
input('');disp((x=str2num(input('','s')))*x')

input('')                                     % Take the first input line and discard
                         input('','s')        % Take the second input as a string 
               x=str2num(input('','s'))       % Convert the string to a list of numbers, x
               (x=str2num(input('','s')))*x'  % Multiply x by x transposed
                                              % This is equivalent to sum(x.^2) but shorter
          disp((x=str2num(input('','s')))*x') % Display the result
```

Call it like this:

```
input('');disp((x=str2num(input('','s')))*x')
5
1 2 5 7 8
143
```

Answer (score 1):

## R, 22 bytes

Nothing very flash, handles the input as specified

```
cat(sum(scan()[-1]^2))
```

Test run

```
> cat(sum(scan()[-1]^2))
1: 5
2: 1 2 5 7 8
7: 
Read 6 items
143
>
```

Answer (score 1):

### Lua, <s>74</s> 62  Bytes

**Edit: saved 8 bytes due to @KennyLau**

It's quite straigthforward, skip the first line and iterate over the group of digits in the second.

```
i,x=io.read,0i()i():gsub("%d+",function(d)x=x+d*d end)print(x)
```

#### Ungolfed

```
x=0
i=io.read 
i()
i():gsub("%d+",function(d)
   x=x+d*d
end)
print(x)
```

Comment: Actually, lua can convert from string to number automatically, so you don't have to do it yourself :)

Comment: Also, this actually takes up less bytes than this:
`x=0i=1print(x..i)`
`x,i=0,1print(x..i)`

Answer (score 0):

## Pyth, 10 bytes

```
sm^sd2ce.z
```

[Try it here!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=sm%5Esd2ce.z&input=5%0A1%202%205%207%208&debug=0)

Takes input in the exact same format as specified in the challenge.

#### Explanation

```
sm^sd2ce.z  # .z = input lines

       e.z  # only take the last line
      c     # split on spaces
 m          # map each number d
   sd       # convert to integer
  ^  2      # square
s           # sum all squares
```

#### Alterntive solutions with more generous input formats

**8 bytes** if I may omit the number count:

```
sm^sd2cz
```

[Try it here!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=sm%5Esd2cz&input=1+2+5+7+8&debug=0)

**4 bytes** if I may take the input as list of integers:

```
s^R2
```

[Try it here!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=s%5ER2&input=%5B1%2C2%2C5%2C7%2C8%5D&debug=0)

Answer (score 0):

### Pyth, 9 bytes

```
s^R2re.z7
```

[Try it here](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=s%5ER2re.z7&input=1+2+5+7+8&debug=0)

Or 7 bytes if allowed to omit line 1

```
s^R2rz7
```

Comment: You're missing the first line of input.

Answer (score 0):

## C,65 bytes

```
j,k;main(i){for(;scanf("%d",&i)+1;j++&&(k+=i*i));printf("%d",k);}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Haskell, 48 bytes

```
main=interact$show.sum.map((^2).read).tail.words
```

How it works:

```
interact                 read whole input, pass it to a function and
                         print it's return value. The function is:

               words     split at whitespace into words
           tail          drop first element (the number on line #1)
    map(       )         convert each word 
           read             to integers
       (^2)                 and square
  sum                    sum all values
show                     convert back to string
```

Answer (score 0):

## [J](http://www.jsoftware.com/help/learning/contents.htm), 4 bytes + 100

```
+/*:
```

[Try it](http://tryj.tk/).

```
   +/*:1 2 5 7 8
143
```

A +100 punishment in the byte-count to myself for not having standard input.

Comment: Add proper input commands please. For some reason this question is _very_ specific about I/O formats, and even normally you can't assume input is in a variable. (And it might be shorter anyway (if you have a 1 or 2 byte input command))

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Does J really have an input command?

Comment: Yes, [J has I/O](http://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/dx001.htm).

Answer (score 0):

### Batch, 76 bytes

```
@set/px=
@set/px=
@set t=0
@for %%n in (%x%)do set/at+=%%n*%%n
@echo %t%
```

Answer (score 0):

## [GS2](https://github.com/nooodl/gs2), 5 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437)

```
W",Φd
```

[Try it online!](http://gs2.tryitonline.net/#code=VyIszqZk&input=NQoxIDIgNSA3IDg)

#### How it works

```
W      Find all numbers in the input; push a list.
 "     Discard the first number.
  ,    Square.
   Φ   Map the last instruction over the list of numbers.
    d  Compute the sum of all squares.
```

Answer (score 0):

## Japt, 8 bytes

```
Ns1 mp x
```

Try it in the [Japt Interpreter](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt?v=master&code=TnMxIG1wIHg=&input=NQoxIDIgNSA3IDg=).

#### How it works

The code is parsed as

```
N.s(1).m(p).x()
```

- `N` is a variable; it contains the parsed input.
- `s(1)` discards the first array element.
- `m(p)` maps `p` (square) over the remaining array.
- `x()` computes the sum of the array of squares.

Answer (score 0):

## [Pylongolf2](https://github.com/lvivtotoro/pylongolf2), 8 bytes

```
c| n²+~
```

```
c  - read the input
|  - split by space (note the 1 space after |)
n  - convert all of that in the list to numbers
²  - Square everything in the list
+  - Sum everything in the list
~  - Print it
```

Answer (score 0):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), 13 bytes

Input is extremely easy for GolfScript.

```
~](;{.*}%{+}*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/vy5Ww7paT6tWtVq7Vuv/f1MuQwUjBVMFcwULAA)

### Explanation

```
~             # Take & Evaluate the input
 ]            # Wrap the whole input into a list
  (;          # Remove the first item
    {.*}%     # Map with squaring
         {+}* # Reduce by summation
```

Answer (score 0):

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), 38 bytes

```javascript
x=>Math.hypot(...x.match(/\s\d+/g))**2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNEts/ifZvu/wtbON7EkQy@jsiC/RENPT69CLzexJDlDQz@mOCZFWz9dU1NLy@h/QVFmXolGmoaScUyeqYKZgrmChZKm5n8A)

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) `S`, 4 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
sON²
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faGm0UrBS7IKlpSVpuhZLi_39Dm1aUpyUXAwVWbDalMtQwUjBVMFcwQIiBAA)

With normal I/O it would be **1 [byte](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)** (with `S` flag):

```
²
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faGm0UrBS7IKlpSVpuhaLDm1aUpyUXAzlLlgfbaijYKSjYKqjYK6jYBELEQYA)

##### Explanation

```python
sON²  # Implicit input
s     # Discard the first input
 O    # Split the second input on spaces
  N   # Convert each string to a number
   ²  # Square each number
      # Implicit output of the sum
```